# Is it possible for a subshell to execute something in the parent shell?

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a shell script which must be `source`d, because its purpose is to set a bunch of environment variables in the current environment.

In case future me forgets, the script begins with:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mustBeSourced() {
  >&2 echo "This script must be sourced."
  exit 1
}

(return 0 2>/dev/null) || mustBeSourced
```

I encounter this situation frequently, for many scripts I use regularly. I'd like to free myself of the need to remember which of my scripts need to be sourced, as well as those little facepalm moments when I forget.

Is there a way for the script to, instead of telling the user to source the script, tell *the calling shell* to source the script?

My calling shell is usually zsh, but I'd accept a solution compatible with bash or dash if it's not possible with zsh. The script is currently written as a bash script, but I have no problem changing it to another shell (or non-shell shebang-compatible language) if it can accomplish what I want.

I have a hunch that this is not possible, at least not without some serious shenanigans.

Comment: In my own bin directory, I have shell scripts whose names start with `.` which, by my own convention, means "this script must be dotted (sourced)".

Comment: @jrw32982supportsMonica does it bother you that they don't show up by default in directory listings?

Comment: I don't normally use `ls` directly, but use a wrapper which includes `-A`, so they *do* show up by default in my directory listings.  I consider "hidden dot files" a bug in the original implementation of `ls` (which it actually was).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zsh`, you can use suffix aliases (see [`info zsh alias`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-alias) for details)

```
alias -s zshenv=source
```

To make sure that when you invoke `some-file.zshenv`, `source some-file.zshenv` is run instead.

Having an executable inject code into its parent process could conceivably be achieved using debuggers, but you don't want to go there.

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't familiar with `-s` and found [this](https://superuser.com/a/864109/305335); might make a good addition to your answer.

Comment: And yeah, "using debuggers" sounds exactly like the sort of serious shenanigans I was worried would be required!